# Is there any way to pause the job and resume the job from that point in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to pause one of the job in jenkins and resume the job from that point.Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) (rather than the older Freestyle job type) then, while a build is running, in the sidebar on the build page, there will be a "Pause/Resume" link.

Comment: I have selected pipeline after click on New item in jenkins but not observed any pause/resume link in jenkins while building the pipeline job.

Comment: @user3065934 What links do you see in the sidebar on the page for the build that's running (i.e. not the job page), when using Pipeline?

Comment: Able to saw the Pause/Resume link in the pipeline job.Thanks

Comment: I can see the link but it is not taking any action after clicking this. It shows the message as done but doesn't pause the build @ChristopherOrr

Comment: You need to click on the build number to see the sidebar menu with pause / resume.

Answer (score 3):

There's also the `input` directive for the new declarative pipeline workflow that you can programmatically set a pause to manually inspect or load something onto some test harness for example.

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#input

Answer (score 0):

Using the Jenkins CLI you can pause and play the jobs. If you would not like to go with CLI mode means, please ignore it.

This may help for who would like to pause the job using Jenkins CLI. But you can resume the job from both UI and CLI.

By following link you can get steps of installation and configuration of Jenkins UI. 
https://stbtestautomation.wordpress.com/2016/08/02/jenkins-pause-and-resume-jobs/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question — this is putting Jenkins into "quiet down" mode, which prevents *any* new jobs from being queued by Jenkins. It doesn't allow to pause/resume individual builds like you can with Pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jenkins API to call what the manual "pause/resume" button would do for a given Job as below.

def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('folder/myjob')

// job.class.methods.collect { it.name }

// assumes a build is already in progress

def build = job.getLastBuild()

// build.class.methods.collect { it.name }

def e = build.getExecution().isPaused()

println e

// toggle the pause statusj

build.getExecution().pause(!e)

See: https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/PauseUnpauseAction.java